# How to filter out a pattern with space in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to filter out a pattern as "-Wl, Bdynamic -lmylib" from a long LDFLAGS list.  But filter-out function can only handle space-separated list, is there other method to do this in Makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it is by replacing spaces with some other character that you know doesn't appear in the variable value.  For example suppose you know that the `^` character never appears in your variable value, then you can do something like this:

```
# Create a variable containing a space
E :=
S := $E $E

LDFLAGS := $(subst ^,$S,$(subst -Wl^Bdynamic^-lmylib,,$(subst $S,^,$(LDFLAGS))))
```